# Force Controller Action to return "Type" as Image and NOT as document

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lightcase.js

Basically, my view is trying to display both thumbnail image and full size image:

```
<img src="/Images/GetImage/60?s=1&t=True" class="" style="width: 100px; height: 80px;" data-id="60" data-source="1">

<img src="/Images/GetImage/60?s=1&t=False" class="" style="width: 100px; height: 80px;" data-id="60" data-source="1">
```

The only thing that changes is the `t` (thumbnail) boolean value.

- When I pass true, the browser http request is interpreted as Type: `jpeg`
- When I pass false, it is interpreted as `document`

Please check the following printscreen:

[image]

How can I really force the Controller Action to return **Type** as `Image` and NOT as `document`?

My actual source code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetImage(int id, EnumImageSource s, bool t)
{
    var backupImagePath = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/Images/PhotoNotAvailable.png"));
    var originalImagePath = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/Images/PhotoNotAvailable.png"));
    var finalImagePath = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/Images/PhotoNotAvailable.png"));            

    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...

    if (model != null)
    {
       ...
       ...
       ...
        originalImagePath = model.Object.Path;                
    }

    if (t)
    {
        var extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(originalImagePath);
        var thumbImagePath = System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(originalImagePath, null) + "_thumb" + extension;
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(thumbImagePath))
        {
            finalImagePath = thumbImagePath;
        }
        else
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(originalImagePath))
            {
                int width;
                int height;
                if (ProcessImage.GetDimentionsByImageType(EnumImageSize.Thumbnail, out width, out height))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (ProcessImage.ResizeImageFile(width, height, originalImagePath, thumbImagePath))
                        {
                            finalImagePath = thumbImagePath;
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                }
            }                    
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(originalImagePath))
        {
            finalImagePath = originalImagePath;
        }
    }
    var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(finalImagePath);
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    return File(bytes, "image/jpeg");
}
```

**UPDATE #1**

As requested by MaKCbIMKo. Yes, if I display the full image next to the thumbnail then both of them are processed as "Image".... but as you can see the way that I am add the "a" html tag is using the same path... however, now it seems that the lightcase.js is somehow processing it as document and not as image, probably by trying to read the "path extension" and match it with image or not... I really think this is the problem now.

```
<div class="img-wrap">
        @if (Model.IsReadOnly == false)
        {
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
        }
        <a href="@(Url.Action("GetImage", "Images", new { area = "", id = i.Id, s = (int)i.ImageSource, t = false }))" data-rel="lightcase:myCollection@(Model.SourceId)" class="showcase">
            <img src="@(Url.Action("GetImage", "Images", new {area = "", id = i.Id, s = (int) i.ImageSource, t = true}))" class="" style="width: 100px; height: 80px;" data-id="@i.Id" data-source="@((int)Model.ImageSource)" />
        </a>
        FULL IMAGE
        <img src="@(Url.Action("GetImage", "Images", new {area = "", id = i.Id, s = (int) i.ImageSource, t = false}))" class="" style="width: 100px; height: 80px;" data-id="@i.Id" data-source="@((int)Model.ImageSource)" />
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'document', as in, what exact content type does your browser report the response as being?

Comment: @christofr Hi, I've included a printscreen on the question description.

Comment: What I'm seeing that the difference not only 'Type' but also 'Initiator'. What if manually type both URLs and check what they will return (without using JS at all)? (maybe it will help to reduce the search area).

Comment: What I found in [lightcase.js](https://github.com/cbopp-art/lightcase/blob/master/src/js/lightcase.js) is that it uses 'html' data type for ajax requests, that will be shown as 'document' but not image.

Comment: @MaKCbIMKo thanks for your input, I have also took a look at their examples from lightcase and they have the same code as me, the only difference is that their "modal window" can be interpreted as image, or html.... and the end result varies from received type: if it is a image cool, just adds the html image tag, if it is a document then it is rendered an iframe with limited height (showing scroll bars)... and that is exactly my issue... so if I am able to make the "return" as image, i do not have the iframe issue.

Comment: Have you tried to call both URLs manually? And, can you share your cshtml fragment?

Comment: @MaKCbIMKo check my UPDATE info on the question description. I think I found the reason... but still without solution (unless if I change directly the JS lightcase source code.

Comment: What I found in lightcase docs is that you should use `<a />` (if I'm not mistaken). But what I can see at the top of your questions is that you have `<img />` tag. That's why I asked you to provide your cshtml code to make verify my idea.

Comment: And in your edit#1 you put tag `<a />` and it worked. What was the initial html code?

Comment: What's the `Content-type` header of the image reported as a document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem was the lightcase.js code....

I just tested a quick change on the source code:

```
createObject: function () {
        var $object;

        // Create object
        switch (_self.objectData.type) {
            ....
         default:

                $object = $(new Image());
                $object.attr({
                    // The time expression is required to prevent the binding of an image load
                    'src': _self.objectData.url,
                    'alt': _self.objectData.title
                });
                break;
```

And now I have the image displayed as image and not inside the iframe....

This is not the final solution, but at least a proof to where the problem lies.

Ok, from here I know what I can do and on how to tackle this.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed two things about lightcase.js:
-They always use link and not an image. Even if image is shown, it is inside `<a>` element. So, try to wrap your `<img />` with `<a>`.
-They check urls for ending in some predefined extensions. Check [source](https://github.com/cbopp-art/lightcase/blob/master/src/js/lightcase.js), from line 114 (typeMapping) and line 752 (_verifyDataType function). It might help if you add dummy query string parameter like:
`Images/GetImage/60?s=1&t=True&type=.jpg`. You will ignore it server side but might help with lightcase

I can't try it right now, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have had strange issues when returning files with **ActionResult** specially file encoding Try returning **FileContentResult**

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas no meu caso nada mudou :P Forca ai na Irlanda.